# Is it possible to enter the US under VWP and depart from Mexico?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, mexico

I would love to get some help regarding the ESTA.

I recently got my ESTA confirmation for my french passport.

I will be flying to the USA from Peru for 4 weeks and from there I'm planing to continue to Mexico for a month travel and from there departure to Israel - without intention to return to the USA (I'm an Israeli citizen).

Today i discovered that "*travelers with onward tickets terminating in Mexico, Canada, Bermuda or the Caribbean Islands must be legal permanent residents of these areas*"

My question is: can I enter the USA with the VWP program in my current condition?

I have a flight from USA to Mexico (my trip is not terminating there) and from there to Israel (not returning to the USA)..

Comment: It's like any flight, they want proof you're either leaving the destination country (Mexico) or have a visa to live there.  Same as you need to prove you'll be leaving the US.

Comment: is that means that my flight ticket from mexico to tel aviv will suit their needs and they will allow me to enter to the usa with the VWP and leave from mexico?

Comment: @Tai yes.  I'm so sure of this that I'm doing it myself in 2 weeks, bussing from LA to Mexico, then flying to Cuba.

Answer (score 4):

**You should be fine**.  Since you're flying onward from Mexico to Israel, you're not "terminating" in Mexico and that rule should not apply.

You'll definitely want to bring along a copy of your ticket, of course.

Comment: the opessite is correct. im entering the us from peru and after staying for 4 weeks in the us i will be flying to mexico and from there to israel. so if i understand you correctly they just need a proof that im not terminating my travels in mexico and ill have no problem to go inside the us even if im leaving back home from mexico

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.  But yes, my answer should still apply, revising now.